# linkDebugFrameworkIosArm64 FAILED

Tags: kotlin, memory-leaks, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm using a KMM shared module with this configuration:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.apple.XCFramework

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.8.21"
}

@OptIn(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
kotlin {
    targetHierarchy.default()

    android {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }


    val xcf = XCFramework()
    listOf(
        iosX64(), iosArm64(), iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "MnghaDataSource"
            xcf.add(this)
        }
        // I added this portion to resolve memory issie on iOS
        it.compilations.configureEach {
            compilerOptions.configure {
                freeCompilerArgs.add("-Xallocator=std")
            }
        }
    }


    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:2.3.4")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:2.3.3")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:2.3.3")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:2.3.4")
                implementation("com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings-no-arg:1.0.0") /* settings library */
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:2.3.3")
            }
        }

        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:2.3.3")
            }
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.ngha_kmp"
    compileSdk = 33
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
    }
}
```

Because of a memory leak issue on the iOS I need to add this code as mentioned in this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-53182/New-memory-manager-Unexpected-memory-usage-on-IOS

```
        it.compilations.configureEach {
            compilerOptions.configure {
                freeCompilerArgs.add("-Xallocator=std")
            }
        }
```

When trying to generate XCFramework by this command `./gradlew assembleXCFramework,`  got this exception:

> > Task :[ProjectName]:linkDebugFrameworkIosArm64 FAILED
>
> e: /Users/.../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-client-content-negotiation-iosarm64/2.3.3/5766ae4dc00f0db02bcd638442975b03b957165f/ktor-client-content-negotiation is cached (in /Users/..../.konan/kotlin-native-prebuilt-macos-aarch64-1.8.21/klib/cache/ios_arm64-gSTATIC/io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation/unspecified/65fdb40ca0c2e3cd1663a0aab362d37bda93c16426ebae286f3d67e085b24244/io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation-cache/bin/libio.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation-cache.a), but its dependency isn't: /Users/..../.konan/kotlin-native-prebuilt-macos-aarch64-1.8.21/klib/common/stdlib
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.